# acceder a directorio desde servidor

Tags: php, mysql, unity

tengo una duda, lo que pasa es que mediante un juego en unity, guardo una imagen en una carpeta que es un screen shot del juego junto con una foto y la quiero subir a una base de datos esa foto, use el siguiente codigo para hacerlo:

```
<?php
include "base.php";
$fecha=$_GET['fecha'];
$numero=$_GET['random'];
$imagen=addslashes(file_get_contents('C:/xampp/htdocs/momiapuerta/img/FotoPuertaPepsi.png'));
$insertar = $enlace->query("INSERT into imagenes (imagen, fecha, random) VALUES ('$imagen', '$fecha', '$numero')");
$fecha1=date('Y-m-d');
$fecha=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($fecha1."- 1 week")); 
$insertar = $enlace->query("DELETE FROM imagenes WHERE fecha<='$fecha'");
unlink('C:/xampp/htdocs/momiapuerta/img/FotoPuertaPepsi.png');
$enlace->close();?>
```

en xampp que es localhost me funciono perfectamente, pero lo subi a godaddy usando un dominio y hosting de ellos y ya no quiere acceder a la carpeta para obtener la foto y subira.
alguien sabe algun codigo de ejemplo para hacer esto o algo que pueda funcionar, porque intente conectarme desde unity y usar mysql ahi pero no he tenido exito para poder mandar algo. la manera en que la quiero subir es de manera automatica accediendo a una url, sin tener que usar un input file, sino que entrando a la url tome esa foto de un directorio, y en la url le especifico unos datos mas a guardar y listo

Comment: La pregunta no se entiende. ¿La foto de dónde la tomas, de una URL? Y ¿dónde la quieres guardar, en la BD o en una carpeta del servidor? En todo caso, ¿cuál es el error?

Comment: la foto la tomo de una carpeta que tengo en mi computadora y la quiero guardar en la base de datos de un servidor en especifico de godaddy y el error es que no me deja entrar a esa carpeta donde esta la foto de mi computadora

Comment: Si la foto está en tu computadora, tienes que recogerla con código cliente (Javascript) y mandarla al servidor usando Ajax o la API Fetch de Javascript o en el peor de los casos un formulario multipart que permita adjuntar archivos. Tienes que entender que, en el momenro en que el servidor es remoto, las cosas cambian, ya no estás en tu computadora y necesitas comunicar entre cliente (tu computadora) y el servidor (GoDaddy).